# CatchError function with ValueFromPipeline

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell function, which i can put into a pipeline after every command I want. It should be able to get the $Error Value from pipeline and write a log.

That's what I have so far:

```
function CatchError
{   
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]$Error,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$OutPath
    )
    Try
    {
        $Error | Out-File $OutPath -Append -Force
    }
    Catch [Exception]
    {
        Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

But when I pipe it like this:

```
gci R:\test | CatchError -OutPath C:\install\test\log.txt
```

log.txt gets created but without any content. the path `R:\test` doesn't exist, so it should create a log file with the content `"R:\test does not exist.. etc."` but it prints out the error exception in powershell window.

How do I stop the error to be printed into powershell window and get it into my logfile instead? I thought `[parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]` already does the trick. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to pass errors by pipeline, then you have to redirect errors to output: `2>&1`.

Comment: @PetSerAl thanks, that worked. is there a way to do this without `2>&1` ?

Comment: I does not know way to do this without redirection. But you possible could change `CatchError` to hide `2>&1` from user. Something like that: `CatchError {gci R:\test} -OutPath C:\install\test\log.txt` and inside `CatchError` you do following: `& $Command 2>&1 | DoSomethingUseful`.

Comment: Not possible without redirection. Instructing your cmdlet to read stuff *out of* the pipeline doesn't magically make that stuff go *into* the pipeline in the first place.

Comment: There might be a way to do it, via reflection & some reverse engineering. The `$host.runspace` object has a private property named `RunningPipelines`, which is a collection, which, for me, has a single item of type LocalPipeline, which in turn has public properties: Error, Input, and Output, and private properties: ErrorStream, InputStream, and OutputStream. So with some in-earnest hacking you could probably get something working. Another option is to write a C# based cmdlet, that will have more discrete access to the various pipelines. Take a look at MSDN for more cmdlet writing info.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this (besides what I mentioned in the comments) is based on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166023/powershell-modify-elements-of-array/34174999#34174999). In particular the part towards the end, where passing a context through the pipeline is discussed. You could do something like the following (thanks to PetSerAl for the idea of passing a script):

```
# Could add try/catch blocks as needed. Keep in mind that errors generated
# within try block are still put into $error (depending on -erroraction
# and $erroractionpreference). 
# Besides extracting errors from $error another option to explore is to use 
# -ErrorVariable when $scriptOrCmdlet was executed, but that would
# only work if a cmdlet or function was passed

# Can pass in anything acceptable to &
function CatchAndWrap-ErrorAtHead ($scriptOrCmdlet) {
  $wasErrorCount = $error.count
  $output = & $scriptOrCmdlet # could accept set of args to this func and pass them here
  $numErrorsToCatch = $error.count - $wasErrorCount
  # Need to wrap everything as an array, so that 2-tuples are in pipeline
  # Not positive @() will do that (versus @(,$output))
  @($output),@($error[0..$numErrorsToCatch])
}

filter Log-PipelinedError {
  $_[1] | Out-File $OutPath -Append -Force
  # Remove logged error(s), but keep 2-tuple intact
  $_ = $_[0], $null
  $_
}

# This function is to insert cmdlets/scripts in the pipeline besides at the head,
# although you could combine the two functions by defining CatchAndWrapHead-Error
# to accept pipeline input
filter CatchAndWrap-ErrorWithin( $script) {
  $wasErrorCount = $error.count
  $output = $_[0] | & $script # again with the args
  $numErrorsToCatch = $error.count - $wasErrorCount

  # Need to decide what to do with errors in the pipe before here
  # This code keeps them, but discarding them is an option
  @($output),@($_[1] + $error[0..$numErrorsToCatch])
}
```

Think of this code as more of a template than a working script. There are probably several devilish details to work through.